# LocalStorage TextBox's in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Weave: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BZVdaM?editors=0010

I'm using LocalStorage to remember the states of <kbd>`input[type=text]`</kbd> elements. I was able to push to a JSON fine

```
{"website": "value","behance": "value","dribbble": "value"}
```

However, my problem now is I'm having difficulty populating the saved data on back in the inputs for page load.

On first run the string returned shouldn't have the quote outside of it; in addition, I noticed after 2nd run it wouldn't show any of the saved data.

Here's the result from Chrome Dev Tools (this is after the 2nd run adding text to another textbox)

[image]

Thus what am I doing wrong?

```js
var arr = localStorage.getItem("socialValues") || {};
if ( localStorage.getItem("socialValues")) {
  var savedArrData = JSON.parse(arr);
  $.each(savedArrData, function(key, value) {
    $("[data-social=links] input#" + key).val(value);
  });
}
$("[data-social=links] input").on("change keyup", function() {
  var id = this.id;
  arr[id] = (this.value ? '"' + this.value + '"' : "");
  localStorage.removeItem("socialValues");
  localStorage.setItem("socialValues", JSON.stringify(arr));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="uk-nav uk-nav-default" data-social="links">
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <span class="uk-margin-small-right" uk-icon="icon: world"></span> 
      <input id="website" class="socialbox" type="text" placeholder="http://yoursite.com/" value="hello world">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <span class="uk-margin-small-right" uk-icon="icon: behance"></span> 
      <input id="behance" class="socialbox" type="text" placeholder="Your behance page">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <span class="uk-margin-small-right" uk-icon="icon: dribbble"></span> 
      <input id="dribbble" class="socialbox" type="text" placeholder="Your dribbble page">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `var arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('socialValues')) || {}` is retrieving the saved json data correctly from localstorage. what do you want to do with this data, its not clear

Comment: Are you asking how to populate the input elements on page load, using the previously stored values?

Comment: @nnnnnn that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had multiple issues in your code

> On first run the string returned shouldn't have the quote outside of it

This is because you're saving the strings with multiple quotes.

```
arr[id] = (this.value ? '"' + this.value + '"' : "");
```

Should be:

```
savedArrData[id] = (this.value ? this.value : "");
```

> in addition, I noticed after 2nd run it wouldn't show any of the saved data.

This is because you load the initial `arr` incorrectly.

```
var arr = localStorage.getItem("socialValues") || {};
```

If the local storage is empty you load an object into `arr`. `localStorage.getItem()` returns a `string` therefore on next loads `arr` holds a `string`. This causes:

```
arr[id] = (this.value ? '"' + this.value + '"' : "");
```

To stop working on the next loads.

So what you need to do is to load string into `arr`, parse it into an object `savedArrData` and then work only on the object.

```
var obj = localStorage.getItem("socialValues") || "{}";
var savedArrData = JSON.parse(obj);

$.each(savedArrData, function (key, value) {
    $("[data-social=links] input#" + key).val(value);
});

$("[data-social=links] input").on("change keyup", function () {
    var id = this.id;
    savedArrData[id] = (this.value ? this.value : "");
    localStorage.removeItem("socialValues");
    localStorage.setItem("socialValues", JSON.stringify(savedArrData));
});
```

Here is a [**working demo**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/weErgv?editors=1010) with all changes

**BTW**

`arr` should be actually named `obj` as its an object rather than an array.

Comment: Thanks for the well-done explanation. This helped! :)

Answer (score 1):

**Few observations :**

- Parse the JSON string which stored in local storage while assigning it into the `arr` variable.

  ```
  var arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("socialValues")) || {};
  ```

**Working Demo**

```js
var arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("socialValues")) || {};

if (localStorage.getItem("socialValues")) {
  var savedArrData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("socialValues"));
  $.each(savedArrData, function(key, value) {
    $("#" + key).val(value);
  });
}

$("[data-social=links] input").on("change keyup", function() {
  var id = this.id;
  arr[id] = (this.value ? this.value : "");
  localStorage.removeItem("socialValues");
  localStorage.setItem("socialValues", JSON.stringify(arr));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="uk-nav uk-nav-default" data-social="links">
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <span class="uk-margin-small-right" uk-icon="icon: world"></span> 
      <input id="website" class="socialbox" type="text" value="hello world">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <span class="uk-margin-small-right" uk-icon="icon: behance"></span> 
      <input id="behance" class="socialbox" type="text" placeholder="Your behance page">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <span class="uk-margin-small-right" uk-icon="icon: dribbble"></span> 
      <input id="dribbble" class="socialbox" type="text" placeholder="Your dribbble page">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

When the page loads, loop through the properties in the JSON you retrieve from `localStorage` and set the values of the corresponding inputs:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var json = localStorage.getItem("socialValues") || "{}";
    var savedData = JSON.parse(json);
    $.each(savedData, function(key, value) {
        $("#" + key).val(value);
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the `arr[id] = (this.value ? '"' + this.value + '"' : "");` to `arr[id] = (this.value ? this.value   : "");`.

```
$("[data-social=links] input").on("change keyup", function() {
  var id = this.id;
  arr[id] = (this.value ? this.value   : "");
  localStorage.removeItem("socialValues");
  localStorage.setItem("socialValues", JSON.stringify(arr));
});
```

Since, you are converting your stored object to string `localStorage.setItem("socialValues", JSON.stringify(savedArrData));`, you don't need to convert while inserting into local storage.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = localStorage.getItem("socialValues") || {};
if ( localStorage.getItem("socialValues")) {
  var savedArrData = JSON.parse(arr);
  $.each(savedArrData, function(key, value) {
    $("[data-social=links] input#" + key).val(value);
  });
}
$("[data-social=links] input").on("change keyup", function() {
  var id = this.id;
  arr[id] = (this.value ? '"' + this.value + '"' : "");
  localStorage.removeItem("socialValues");
  localStorage.setItem("socialValues", JSON.stringify(arr));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="uk-nav uk-nav-default" data-social="links">
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <span class="uk-margin-small-right" uk-icon="icon: world"></span> 
      <input id="website" class="socialbox" type="text" placeholder="http://yoursite.com/" value="hello world">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <span class="uk-margin-small-right" uk-icon="icon: behance"></span> 
      <input id="behance" class="socialbox" type="text" placeholder="Your behance page">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <span class="uk-margin-small-right" uk-icon="icon: dribbble"></span> 
      <input id="dribbble" class="socialbox" type="text" placeholder="Your dribbble page">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```